# Finding the best person in an array

Tags: java

I have an array called Names[5] and one called scores[5][5].
Each row corresponds with the name in the respective index.

I need to find the highest score in the scores array and return the name that corresponds with it.

This is what I have so far:

```
int high = 0;
for(a=0; a<5; a++)
    for(b=0; b<5; b++)
        if(high<scores[a][b])
```

Comment: OK.  So where are you stuck?  How far have you gotten?  What exactly do you need help figuring out?

Comment: You need to use a better data structure.

Comment: i know i am going to need a dubble for loop just now sure how the logic is going to work on it

Comment: int high = 0;
    for(a=0; a<5; a++)
        for(b=0; b<5; b++)
          if(high<scores[a][b])
            
THis is what i have so far

Comment: Also get in to the habit of using braces even when you don't need to.  Remember code is for humans to read not computers.  The compiler doesn't care if you have "extra" braces or not, but as a human its better to be consistent and always have braces.  It vastly improves readability

Answer (score 4):

Just scan the matrix, and remember the best score and best name so far. 
Something like:

```
String[] names = {"a","b","c","d","e"};
int[][] scores = new int[5][5];
//... init scores

int best = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
String bestName = null;
for(int nm = 0;nm<5;nm++){
    for(int c = 0;c<5;c++){
        int score = scores[nm][c];
        if (score>=best){
            best = score;
            bestName = names[nm];
        }
    }
}
System.out.println(bestName);
```

Comment: ugh O(N^2) for something that should be O(1). Data structures people.

Comment: What does the Int best = Integer.Min_value do

Comment: @Byron: Assuming that we have control on the process of collecting the scores, we can maintain the best score & person during this process, and then return it in O(1). But the question refers to a given situation where the data is already in a matrix. There is no better solution here than O(n^2)

Comment: @dalton: I initialize the variable *best* with the smallest possible integer. This way I guarantee that the first score encountered in the double loop will override it and set the corresponding name as well. Any other initialization value may cause the loop to terminate with bestName == null

Comment: Integer.Min_Value returns the smallest possible value of int. In this case, it initializes the best score variable with the minimum value of int. You could initialize best with 0, but the answerer doesn't know if negative scores are going to be in your array, which would return the wrong answer. The minimum value of int is negative 2^16.

Comment: @Josh: actually the minimum value of int is -2^31. Ints in Java are 32 bit.

Comment: @Eyal maybe should have looked that up first hey. I figured int was 32bits wide, but would be -2^16 to + 2^16. Unless it was unsigned which would be +2^32. But no, I'm wrong.